# defined ansible vars is reported as undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team: I have already defined the var device_pattern in defaults/main.yaml and am referring it or using it for compare against ansible_facts but I get error it is not defined? what is the catch?
when below is failing..

```
device_pattern: "nvme"
```

`'nvme' is undefined\n\`

```
fatal: [xxxxxxx]: FAILED! => {
14:14:44      "msg": "The conditional check '{{ device_pattern }} in ansible_devices[item]' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ device_pattern }} in ansible_devices[item]): 'nvme' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave1/workspace/run_ansible_playbook/k8s/baremetal/roles/local_volume_mount/tasks/main.yml': line 45, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n#MDM RAID0 All available free unmounted devices\n- name: \"Perform MDM Raid0 on all qualifying available devices on any cpu node\"\n  ^ here\n"
14:14:44  }
```

task is

```
#MDM RAID0 All available free unmounted devices
- name: "Perform MDM Raid0 on all qualifying available devices on any cpu node"
  include_tasks:
    file: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm.yml
    apply:
      tags: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm
  when:
    - '{{ device_pattern }} in ansible_devices[item]'
```

Comment: When conditionals must not contain Jinja2 markets => `when: device_pattern in ansible_devices[item]`

Answer (score 0):

figured out in when no quotes needed.

```
#MDM RAID0 All available free unmounted devices
- name: "Perform MDM Raid0 on all qualifying available devices on any cpu node"
  include_tasks:
    file: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm.yml
    apply:
      tags: pfm_all_available_devices_mdm
  when:
    - device_pattern in ansible_devices[item]
```